# Постановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

«Пугачёв дал знак и меня тотчас отпустили». Запятая ставится ли перед союзом **и**?

Answer (score 4):

**Запятая ставится**: **Пугачёв дал знак**, и меня тотчас **отпустили**.

Это сложносочиненное предложение, нормой является постановка запятой.  Второе предложение односоставное (нет грамматического подлежащего).

Запятая не ставится только при наличии общего элемента (обстоятельства, вводного слова и др.), которые связывают предложение в одну фразу.

Comment: Вводного слова - нет.

Comment: Если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общее вводное слово, общий обособленный член или общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения: ***Словом***, время уже истекло и пора было уходить; Вопреки предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал

Comment: Здесь разве не вводное слово?